HttpClientHandler - setting ClientCertificate at runtime
We have an ASP.NET Core 8 application (migrated from older frameworks) that integrates with a number of 3rd party services via http; some of those 3rd parties require a client certificate.
We manage the certificates via 'runtime configuration' - that is, we know the thumbprint(s) ONLY at the time we are about to make the request and NOT when we are initializing the application. this allows us to change out the certificates 'on the fly' without redeploying the application.
We have a more-or-less working implementation, but it doesn't use HttpClientFactory; it creates a new HttpClient with a new handler passed to the constructor (with some caching to avoid creating tons of new HttpClient).
We're looking into using HttpClientFactory if possible, but I'm getting stuck

when doing the HttpClient registration, we don't/can't know the thumbprint(s) we need
when we are making the request, we know the thumbprint, but we don't have a reference to the handler (and I can't figure out how to get one)
because the handlers are pooled, I'm wary of adding a client certificate on a handler that could be shared with another integration (this is more surmountable; we have few enough of these integrations that we could create a named client/custom handler for each one)

So my main question is: how to pass 'runtime' information to the handler?
With a secondary question about gotchas in adding client certificate to a potentially pooled handler.

Do you mean you want to set the httpclient's certficate per request?

more or less. we're likely to use the same certificate for some time, but it could change at any point

In my opinion, I suggest you could consider register a httpclienthandler with the scoped and a service to get the certificate to see if this will achieve your requirement or not.

what i'm probably going to do is

implement a "certificate cache" service such that i can store the hostname -> cert link before making the request
use SocketsHttpHandler with a named client and implement SslOptions.LocalCertificateSelectionCallback to then retrieve the cert from the 'cache' based on the host name

this isn't perfect, as requests arriving in our application 'out of order' may overwrite each other, but i think it's a fairly low risk for our specific scenario
i've got an implementation that seems to run, but i have yet to test it against the actual 3rd party integration
